# cant read file from system32 folder

Tags: vb.net, windows, system32

I am developing a vb.net application.

I have made my own file and put in the system32 folder.

Now,I am trying to read same file which I have put in the folder with below code...

```
         Try
            Dim FileData As String = ""
            Dim line As String = "'"
            Dim readFile As System.IO.TextReader = New StreamReader("C:\Windows\System32\winApps.dll")
            While True
            .
            .
            .
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Close()
        End Try
```

But whenever I run above code, its gives an error - at readFile statement...

> Could not find file 'C:\Windows\System32\winApps.dll'.

but file do exist there...but if I change the files location code runs without an error.

[image]

I have administrative rights.

What I am missing ?

Comment: [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).

Comment: Try running the application "as administrator", though file system redirection sounds more likely.

Comment: checked, Not working...

Comment: Does your file *really* belong in a subdirectory of "Windows", or would it be better if it was somewhere in "Program Files" (or "Program Data" as it appears you are regarding it as a text file)?

Comment: Trying to read text from a DLL is not a sensible thing to do.  The default settings of a VB project will get you to read only files from c:\windows\syswow64.